# Why is the value assigned to all arrays instead of just the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does table[0][0] = 2 not only assign that value to the first item in the first array?

```js
let table = new Array(3).fill(Array(3));

table[0][0] = 2;
console.log(table);
```

```
output: [ [ 2, ,  ], [ 2, ,  ], [ 2, ,  ] ]
```

Comment: Because `fill` uses references to the same array object to fill the nested array.

Comment: @JamesJavascript I had this same issue a while back trying to do `.fill([])`. Instead of using `.fill(Array(3))` here, use `.fill().map(e => Array(3).fill())`